# ReferenceError: function is not defined?

Tags: cakephp, google-maps-api-3

I have implemented googleMap api on my site but I keep getting the following error messages:

```
ReferenceError: deleteOverlays is not defined
ReferenceError: clearOverlays is not defined
```

javascript that I am using in the home.php:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' , drawMap);  
  var map,line;
  var locationsArray = new Array();
  var linesArray = new Array();
   var markersArray = new Array();
    function drawMap()
    {
    var myCenter =new google.maps.LatLng(24.87877,67.06403);

   var mapProp = {                                              
  center:myCenter,
  zoom:14,

mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
 heading: 90,
 tilt: 45
 };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);  


var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: myCenter,    

 });
 marker.setMap(map);  

}); 


 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {           
 placeMarker(event.latLng);
 });
 function placeMarker(location) {
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
 position: location,
  map: map
 });
markersArray.push(marker);    
 }
  var polyOptions = {

 strokeColor: '#000000',
 strokeOpacity: 1.0,
 strokeWeight: 3
  };

 poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
 poly.setMap(map);

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', placeLine);
```

and my functions is:

```
 function deleteOverlays() {
 alert("enter in function above th if condition");
   if (markersArray) {
    for (var i=0; i<markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
   }
    markersArray.length = 0;
 if (linesArray) {
  for (var i=0; i<linesArray.length; i++) {
    linesArray[i].setMap(null);
 }
linesArray.length = 0;
 }

}
function clearOverlays() {
 alert("enter in function");
 if (markersArray) 
    {
        var markersArraylength = markersArray.length -1;
        markersArray[markersArraylength].setMap(null);
        markersArray.pop();

        locationsArray[markersArraylength] = null;
        locationsArray.pop();
    }

    if (linesArray) 
    {   
        var linesArraylength = linesArray.length -1;
        linesArray[linesArraylength].setMap(null);
        linesArray.pop();
    }
   }
   function placeLine(event){       
linesArray =  poly.getPath();
    linesArray.push(event.latLng);      
  }
}
```

This is the code I am using for calling function:

```
<input type="button" id="deletelastmarker" value="Delete Last marker"    onclick="clearOverlays()"></input>     
<input type="button" id="deleteallmarker" value="Delete all markers" onclick="deleteOverlays()"></input>
```

how can i solve the above problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a function as an HTML onclick function, it *must* be in the global scope.